# "safely remove hard drive" is not always enabled

Tags: hard-drive

my ubuntu is not always has option to remove the drive safely. sometime there is option to remove it safely and sometime there is no option to remove it safely and its not only happening to one drive.

1. how important we need to remove our hard drive safely?
2. how to remove our hard drive safely if there is not option to remove it safely?

Comment: I too get " Eject " option instead of " Safely Remove Drive " option, mostly. Not sure whether is device specific. I use only my smart phone and USB drives on 16.04

Comment: no eject option too only amount. i am afraid it will cause damage to my hard drive permanently if i keep removing it unsafely :(

Comment: It could be a bug, who knows.

Answer (score 4):

There is option to power off device in `disks` (gnome-disk-utilit) app:

1. Go to activities (click super key on keyboard or top left corner on main desktop)
2. Type `disks` and open the app
3. Unmount all mounted partitions from external device and click power off button on right corner

Answer (score 1):

There are different situations:

1. There might be process using a file on that drive

   - By removing the drive suddenly they might crash.
2. There might be process writing something to drive

   - Remove it and you lose anything that is begin written to drive.
3. There might be something in the buffer not yet stored in the disk.

   - Again, if you remove it you lose it
4. While disk being used (mostly begin written to), removing it might cause different scenarios too, like a broken file system.

What I do to remove a drive safely is:

1. Make sure nothing is left in buffer and everything has been written to disk.

   ```
   sync
   ```
2. Unmount it, which makes us shore no one has any business with disk:

   ```
   sudo umount /dev/sdb1
   ```
3. Power off it:

   ```
   udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
   ```

---

Also I wrote an script to do these stuff automatically, [here](https://github.com/ravexina/scripts/blob/master/unmount.sh) you can get it.

Comment: 1. how about electric thing? i have heard if we dont remove it safely, it will cause damage to hard drive. 2. so if we unmount all partititon of our hard drive, is it safe enough to unplug it without "remove it safely"?

Comment: and i think i already closed all opened file but still no "remove it safely" option.

Comment: If you `umount` it, you know it's not being used anymore. then after powering it of, it gets detached from the system (like safely remove) and it will be more safe to remove it . About the hard disk itself, yeah it might cause some problems just like another electronic stuff when suddenly gets power down.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that these may be Western Digital drives?

In `Nautilus`, if you click the eject button next to the drive name it'll eject the drive, **and** then right-click on the drive name, you should see the `remove drive safely` option.

If not, the safest way is to power off the computer, then remove the drives from their USB port.